# Convert a list to a numpy mask array

Tags: python, numpy

Given list like `indice = [1, 0, 2]` and dimension `m = 3`, I want to get the mask array like this

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mask_array = np.array([ [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1] ])  
>>> mask_array
  [[1, 1, 0],    
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1]]
```

Given `m = 3`, so the `axis=1` of `mask_array` is `3`, the row of `mask_array` indicates the length of `indice`.

For converting the `indice` to `mask_array`, the rule is marking the item values whose index is less or equal to the each entry of inside to value 1. For example, `indice[0]=1`, so the output is `[1, 1, 0]`, given dimension is 3.

In NumPy, are there any APIs which can be used to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) with `arange(m)`, make sure to use an `np.array` for the `indices`, not a list...

```
>>> indice = [1, 0, 2]
>>> m = 3
>>> np.arange(m) <= np.array(indice)[..., None]
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Note, the `[..., None]` just reshapes the indices array so that the broadcasting works like we want, like this:

```
>>> indices = np.array(indice)
>>> indices
array([1, 0, 2])
>>> indices[...,None]
array([[1],
       [0],
       [2]])
```

Comment: I cannot stop accepting your answer, brilliant idea